# queue of key value future tasks

Tags: asynchronous, dart, flutter, queue

I want to create a queue of future tasks, with a key to avoid to add to the queue the same task already added.

This is my scenario:

- async call to url1
- async call to url1
- async call to url2

What I need is:

- add call to url1 to the queue and execute it
- DO NOT add the second call to url1 to the queue and throw away it
- add call to url2 to the queue, wait for call to url1 to be finished, and execute it

I read about StreamQueue and Queue, but I do not know if it fits for my needs.

Another structure I read about is `await for` with stream.

So I tried with something like:

```
await for (var url in stream) { // <--- I do not know how create this stream
  var url = Uri.https('www.example.com', url);

  List<dynamic> tmpItems;

  try {
    http.Response res = await http.get(url);
    final data = json.decode(res.body);
    tmpItems = _parseItems(data["data"]);
  } catch(e) {
    print(e);
  }

  if (this.mounted) {
    return setState(() {
      _items.addAll(tmpItems ?? []);
    });
  }
}
```

I do not know howto create `stream` and add to call to it.

Answer (score 0):

ok first you need to have a urlArray that have the urls then implement an async method called getUrl as an example and implement it to get the data from the url this method takes the url as a parameter

```
Future getData(url,index) async {
       //here you can call the function and handle the output(return value) as result
       getUrl(url).then((result) {
           // print(result);
           //here check if index is smaller than the array length-1
           //if true then call getData function again to get next url
           if(index<urlArray.length)
           {
             --index;
             getData(urlArray[index],index);
            }
      });
 }
```

so the first call will be something like that getData(urlArray[0],0)